# How can I get the value of an input in a specific table cell using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm wondering how can I get the value of an `input` in a specific table cell using javascript?

```
<td><input type="text"/></td>
```

I assume getting the `innerHTML` of a specific cell is quite simple, for example:

```
var x = document.getElementById("tabela").rows[2].cells[3].innerHTML
```

but this gives me just the `input` without it's `value`. Adding `.value` to the end of the line doesn't work. I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you add a `class` or `id` attribute to your input field?

Comment: Are you allowed to use jquery?

Comment: Try this `var x = document.getElementById("tabela").rows[2].cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value`

Comment: Well, `innerHTML` would yield nothing, as it's givving you everything between the start of the tag and its end, however, since you (essentially) have `<input></input>` there is nothing there, thus it'd return an empty string. Everything up to that point is correct, assuming the selectors you used point to that input, so you should be able to use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Correction to myself, I just realized what you're getting is the cell, rather than the input - yes, `innerHTML` would give you the input tag. But to actually get its value, you need to access, the tag itself - there are answers on this page that show how to do that. Getting the HTML for it is not useful, as you are better of getting the DOM node and manipulate that.

Comment: thank you guys - that was my first ask on SO. I didnt know you are that fast and helpful :). Adding children[0].value to the end of the line gave me the input value...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't have any `id` on the element you are after, then you could get the first child of the `td` by:

```
var x = document.getElementById("tabela").rows[n].cells[n].children[0].value;
```

Or if you want the first child to be specific to input then:

```
var x = document.getElementById("tabela").rows[n].cells[n].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `firstChild.value` like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("tabela").rows[2].cells[3].firstChild.value;
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9MF3m/5/)

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide id to your input element,

HTML

```
<td><input type="text" id="text1"/></td>
```

JS

```
var x = document.getElementById("text1").value;
```

Comment: But if they're in a table, what is the ID?

Comment: OP did not mention any restriction for providing id to input elements. Else he could go by abhitalks answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) DOM method:

```
document.querySelector('#tabela tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) > input').value
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raPK6/)