# Javascript getting the value of an input in a table

Tags: javascript, html, input, html-table

I'm just wondering if it's possible to get the value of an html input in a table without naming each input separately and using getElementById directly onto the input so if I had the following table

```
<table id="table01">
<tr>
    <td>row 0 cell 0</td>
    <td>row 0 cell 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row 1 cell 0</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I know in Javascript you can use the following to get the value of a specific cell in a specific row using the following

```
var lv_value = document.getElementById("table01").rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML;
console.log(lv_cont);
```

and this would give me the value I want which is "row 0 cell 1".

If I had a table like the following however

```
<table id="table01">
<tr>
    <td>row 0 cell 0</td>
    <td>row 0 cell 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="tbl_input"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row 1 cell 0</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="tbl_input"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is it then possible to do something along the lines of

```
<!-- this is obviously wrong -->
var lv_input = document.getElementById("table01").rows[0].cells[2].input.value;
console.log(lv_input);
```

to get the value of the input in the first row

Comment: Or [How can I get the value of an input in a specific table cell using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307292/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-an-input-in-a-specific-table-cell-using-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

You should do something like this:

```
var lv_input = document.getElementById("table01").rows[0].cells[2].firstChild.value;
console.log(lv_input);
```

or use the `querySelector` to find the input element

```
var lv_input = document.getElementById("table01").rows[0].cells[2].querySelector('input').value;
console.log(lv_input);
```